# Why does bash set $? (exit status) to non-zero on Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Z?

Tags: bash, command-line, background-process, signals, exit-status

From the bash manual, on the [`$?` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_0024_003f):

> `$?` Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed
>   foreground pipeline.

I wonder why bash updates the `$?` variable on pressing `Ctrl-C` or `Ctrl-Z`:

```
$ echo $?
0
$ ^C
$ echo $?
130
$ sleep 10
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 10
$ echo $?
148
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> on the command line, nothing exits, but the handler for `SIGINT` ([`sigint_sighandler()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/sig.c#n614)) sets the exit status to 130 (128 + 2, as DopeGhoti's answer explains) anyway:

```c
if (interrupt_immediately)
  {
    interrupt_immediately = 0;
    last_command_exit_value = 128 + sig;
    throw_to_top_level ();
  }
```

And in [`throw_to_top_level()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/sig.c#n400):

```c
if (interrupt_state)
  {
    if (last_command_exit_value < 128)
    last_command_exit_value = 128 + SIGINT;
    print_newline = 1;
    DELINTERRUPT;
  }
```

When you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to kill a background process, the shell observes that the process has died and also sets the exit status `$?` to 128 plus the signal number.

When you press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> to suspend a background process, the shell observes that something has happened to the process: it hasn't died, but the information is reported through the same system call (`wait` and friends). Here as well, the shell sets the exit status `$?` to 128 plus the signal number, which is 148 (SIGTSTP = 20).

Comment: Cool. Any clue how come it's set to 148 on `Ctrl-Z` ?

Comment: @eugeney Ctrl-Z is SIGTSTP, which is signal 20. (See [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).)

Comment: Does the process actually exit in this case, or this is again handled by bash somehow?

Comment: No, the process doesn't exit (that would be a bug), it is stopped. Again, in this case, the exit status is set by `throw_to_level()` (see the lines immediately after those which I quoted).

Answer (score 9):

Because `0` is the exit code for a normal exit state.

Intercepting an Interrupt or Break signal is not a usual exit state, nor is being suspended to the background.  The non-zero exit codes tell you this is what is happening so that you can react accordingly in a script if the job it fires off is killed or suspended rather than exiting conventionally with a non-error state.

The interactive shell session, when you press <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, which throws a `SIGINT` signal (signal 2), aborts the current interactive command entry, which is a non-normal state for the command entry (i. e. the command prompt) to be in. This causes it to return status 130 (128+2), and give you a new prompt.

More details can be found at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF.

Comment: I agree, but what process does exit when I just press `Ctrl-C` in bash?

Comment: The interactive shell session, when you press `^C`, which throws a `SIGINT` signal (signal 2), aborts the current interactive command entry, which is a non-normal state for the command entry (i. e. the command prompt) to be in.  This causes it to return status 130 (128+2), and give you a new prompt.

Comment: That comment ^ should be part of the answer.

Comment: I shall make it so.

Answer (score 1):

The standard says that the value in `$?` in case on a received signal is `> 128` but the standard does not say how this has to be done.

The Bourne Shell sets `$?` in case of a singal, it uses `128 + signal number`

ksh93 uses `256 + signal number`

Note that only signal numbers  1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 14, and 15 are portable.

In other words: SIGTSTP and SIGSTOP use non-portable numbers.

For this reason, the Bourne Shell recently introduced a new portable system, see http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html see the  ${.sh.termsig} variable.