# What's the meaning of the numbers with the red background in Linux Lite's terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

I've been using [Linux Lite](https://www.linuxliteos.com/)  for a couple of months but I never figured out what's the meaning of the numbers with red background in the terminal.

[image]

I couldn't find a meaning after googling it or looking up at the xfce documentation.

Comment: In all likelihood, the exit status of the previous command if it was non-zero. Also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251996/70524, with Ctrl-C matching up with the exit status of 130, even though nothing exited.

Comment: That looks like it's part of your shell's prompt. What's your shell, what's the output of `typeset -p PS1`? (which on Korn-like shell should print the prompt variable definition)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas

`declare -- PS1="\\[\\] USER \\[\\] \\[\\]~ \\[\\] \\[\\]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the exit code. I can die in peace.

Thanks to [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru)